# Given three plots of trigonometric functions, find an expression for each function

Tags: trigonometry

Considering the three graphs in figure 1 showing trigonometric functions, $f(x)$, $g(x)$ and $h(x)$. Using these graphs, write the expression for each function.

[image: http://tinypic.com/r/2iq13r/5]

Comment: your title sounds like you're begging.

Comment: Did you try to solve this problem?

Answer (score 5):

Hints:  They are all sine waves, so of the form $y=a\sin(bx+c)+d$  Where can you find $a$?  Where do they go through $0$?  What is the period?  Yes, you could use $\cos$ as well.

Comment: I think that for f we will need a +d to describe it.

Comment: @cand:  yes, for at least two of them, because they are not centered on $y=0$.  Added

Answer (score 0):

I will solve g(x) so you can learn by example. This function is clearly a cosine or sine function, I will use cosine to describe it. These funcions are written in the form y=a*cos(bx-c)+d. Let's start with a. a represents the amplitude of the trig function. The amplitude is the distance between the crest and the trough, divided by 2. The distance is 2, and when divided by 2 equals 1. The b coefficient can be found from the period. The equation to find the period is 2pi/b. So then b=2pi/(period). It seems the period is 2pi/3. Plugged in for b=2pi/(2pi/3)=3. I forgot to mention this before, but this is a negative cosine function. Its basically flipped across the x-axis. c is the displacement of the function in the x-direction from the basic cosx function. There is no displacement, its just flipped over the x-axis so the value is 0. d is the displacement in the y-direction. There is no displacement. So the value is 0. Therefore, the whole function in the form y=a*cos(bx-c)+d is y=-1*cos(3x-0)+0=-cos(3x). Sorry if my answer is a bit too wordy.